# How in store object to get access to parent vue page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vee-validate

In my vue 2.6/cli 4/vuex 3.1 app I update some data in store vuex, like in src/store/index.js :

```
userPropStore(context, userProp ) {
    bus.$emit( 'beforeUserPropStore', userProp );
    let apiUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
    Vue.http.post(apiUrl + '/personal/user-props', userProp).then(({data}) => {
        let userProps= this.getters.userProps
        userProps.push({
            "id": data.user_props.id,
            "name": data.user_props.name,
            "value": data.user_props.value,
            "created_at": data.user_props.created_at,
        })
        this.commit('refreshUserProps', userProps);
        bus.$emit( 'onUserPropStoreSuccess', data );
    }, error => {
        console.log('context::')
        console.log(context)
        console.error(error)
        self.$refs.userObserverForm.setErrors(error.body.errors)
    });
}, // userPropStore(context, userProp ) {
```

and using ValidationProvider of vee-validate 3.2 I want to catch server errors (like not unique item)
but I got error :

```
index.js?4360:847 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'userObserverForm' of undefined
```

on line

```
self.$refs.userObserverForm.setErrors(error.body.errors)
```

If there is a way in store object to get access to parent page, maybe with context, which has : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMqic.jpg
?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very strange implementation.

Obviously `self.$refs.userObserverForm.setErrors(error.body.errors)` fails because you are NOT in a component, which is where $refs is available.

What you have to do in your `catch` block is setting the errors in Vuex and then make your component read from there.

Pseudocode follows:

I don't understand what your bus is doing... I guess you use it to send data to your component, but why use `Vuex` then?

```
userPropStore(context, userProp ) {
    bus.$emit( 'beforeUserPropStore', userProp );
    let apiUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
    Vue.http.post(apiUrl + '/personal/user-props', userProp).then(({data}) => {
        let userProps= this.getters.userProps
        userProps.push({
            "id": data.user_props.id,
            "name": data.user_props.name,
            "value": data.user_props.value,
            "created_at": data.user_props.created_at,
        })
        this.commit('refreshUserProps', userProps);
        bus.$emit( 'onUserPropStoreSuccess', data );
        commit('SET_USER_PROPS, data)
    }, error => {
        console.log('context::')
        console.log(context)
        console.error(error)
        commit('SET_USER_PROPS_ERRORS', error.body.errors)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this in the past is to return the promise that `Vue.http.post` produces and then do what you want in your component with the failure information:

```
userPropStore(context, userProp ) {
    bus.$emit( 'beforeUserPropStore', userProp );
    let apiUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
    //add return to the line below
    return Vue.http.post(apiUrl + '/personal/user-props', userProp).then(({data}) => {
```

Then over in your component:

```
loadData() {
    this.$store.dispatch('userPropStore').catch((error) => {
        this.$refs.userObserverForm.setErrors(error.body.errors)
        //any other things you want to do "in component" goes here
    });
}
```